# Shift time series to start from zero H:M:S:MS (possibly in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, date, time

I have some ECG data for a number of subjects. For each subject, I can export an excel file with the RR interval, Heart Rate and other measures. The problem is that I have a timestamp starting at the time of recording (in this case 11:22:3:00).
I need to compare the date with other subjects and I want to automate the procedure in Matlab.

I need to flexibly compare, for instance, the first 3 minutes of subjects in condition 1 with those of sbj in condition 2. Or minutes 4 to 8 of condition 1 and 2 and so forth. To do this, I am thinking that the best way is to shift the time vector for each subject so that it starts from 0.

There are a couple of problems to note: I CANNOT create just one vector for all subjects. This would be inaccurate because the heart measures are variable for each individual.

So, **IN SHORT** I need to shift the time vector for each participant so that it starts at 0 and increases exactly like the original one. So, in this example:

```
  H: M: S: MS    RR         HR
 11:22:03:000   0.809   74.1
 11:22:03:092   0.803   74.7
 11:22:03:895   0.768   78.1
 11:22:04:663   0.732   81.9
 11:22:05:395   0.715   83.9
 11:22:06:110   0.693   86.5
 11:22:06:803   0.705   85.1
 11:22:07:508   0.706   84.9
 11:22:08:214   0.749   80.1
 11:22:08:963   0.762   78.7
 11:22:09:725   0.766   78.3
```

would become:

```
00:00:00:0000
00:00:00:092
00:00:00:895
00:00:01:663
```

and so forth...

I would like to do it in Matlab...

P.S.
I was working around the idea of extracting the info in 4 different variables.
Then, I could subtract the values for each cell from the first cell.
For instance:

```
 11-11 = 0; 22-22=0; 03-03=0; ms: keep the same value
```

Maybe this could kind of work, except that it wouldn't if I have a subject that started, say, at 11:55:05:00

Thank you all for any help.

Gluce

Comment: P.S. the overall recording is 26 minutes, so I could get rid of hours in the final time variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic timestamp normalization just subtracts the minimum (or first, assuming they're properly ordered) time from the rest.

With MATLAB's [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) object, this is just subtraction, which yields a [`duration`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html) object:

```
ts = ["11:22:03:000", "11:22:03:092", "11:22:03:895", "11:22:04:663"];

% Convert to datetime & normalize
t = datetime(ts, 'InputFormat', 'HH:mm:ss:SSS');
t.Format = 'HH:mm:ss:SSS';
nt = t - t(1);

% Reformat & display
nt.Format = 'hh:mm:ss.SSS';
```

Which returns:

```
>> nt

nt = 

  1×4 duration array

   00:00:00.000   00:00:00.092   00:00:00.895   00:00:01.663
```

Alternatively, you can normalize the `datetime` array itself:

```
ts = ["11:22:03:000", "11:22:03:092", "11:22:03:895", "11:22:04:663"];
t = datetime(ts, 'InputFormat', 'HH:mm:ss:SSS');
t.Format = 'HH:mm:ss:SSS';

[h, m, s] = hms(t);
[t.Hour, t.Minute, t.Second] = deal(h - h(1), m - m(1), s - s(1));
```

Which returns the same:

```
>> t

t = 

  1×4 datetime array

   00:00:00:000   00:00:00:092   00:00:00:895   00:00:01:663
```

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply.
Anyways, that worked like a charm. Thank you very much, I appreciate.